# Store typed array in ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, endianness, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I have an ArrayBuffer of data which is composed of Uint8s. Each is in network byte order (big-endian). My goal is to convert each Uint8 into little-endian order, but then put them back in the ArrayBuffer.

I know I can easily separate the individual Uints by using a typed array, like so:

```
var uintArr = new Uint8Array(ArrayBuffer);
```

From there I can swap the endian-ness of each item, and have an array of little-endian Uint8s.

What I don't know is how to get that array back into an ArrayBuffer.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayBuffer is a common byte array for all the views. Typed array simply means there is an associated type on the array such as uint8, int16 etc. All Uin8Array, Int32Array etc. are *views* on top of the ArrayBuffer to enable reading and writing in the type they represent.

(U)int8 arrays does not have byte-order as they are single bytes (ie. nothing to reorder). The bytes need to represent something wider such as (u)int-16 or -32 (64-bit integers are not supported until ES7, but you do have 32-bit and 64-bit IEEE floats).

Anything you read or write through views ends back up in the same ArrayBuffer they point to - you can even have several views for the same buffer.

To swap order for 16-bit you can simply read the ArrayBuffer using a Uint16Array view and swap manually:

```
var buffer16 = new Uint16Array(buffer); // use same buffer as for the Uin8Array view

for(var i = 0, v; i < buffer16.length; i++) {
  v = buffer16[i];
  buffer16[i] = ((v & 0xff) << 8) | ((v & 0xff00) >>> 8);  // mask and shift the two bytes
}
```

If you had a 8-bit view for the same buffer you can now read individual bytes with the new order.

For 32-bits you would do:

```
var buffer32 = new Uint32Array(buffer);

for(var i = 0, v; i < buffer32.length; i++) {
  v = buffer32[i];
  buffer32[i] = ((v & 0xff) << 24) |       // mask, move byte 0 to 3
                ((v & 0xff00) << 8) |      // mask, move byte 1 to 2
                ((v & 0xff0000) >>> 8) |   // mask, move byte 2 to 1 unsigned
                ((v & 0xff000000) >>> 24); // mask, move byte 3 to 0 unsigned
}
```

However, these views require aligned buffers meaning the length of the buffer for (u)int16 must be aligned for even lengths, while 32-bits must be aligned to 4 bytes.

If the buffer is not you can instead use a DataView to read and write any lengths, at any position at the cost of some performance:

```
var view = new DataView(buffer);
var alignedLength = ((buffer.length / 2)|0) * 2;  // aligned to 16-bit

// 16-bit
for(var i = 0, v; i < alignedLength; i += 2) {
  v = view.getUint16(i, false);  // read as big-endian
  view.setUint16(i, v, true);    // write as little-endian
}
```

and for 32-bits use getUint32/setUint32 instead, incrementing `i` with 4. Note you have to "keep an eye on" the last read in case the ArrayBuffer is not aligned to 2 or 4 bytes (usually you would align the buffer.length and use that in the loop as shown, use 4's for 32-bit).

If your source buffer is containing mixed lengths (for example if it contains a raw binary file) you will have to parse each value in accordance to the file format specification. For this, use the DataView.

## Examples

```js
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4),
    b8 = new Uint8Array(buffer),
    b16 = new Uint16Array(buffer),
    b32 = new Uint32Array(buffer),
    view = new DataView(buffer);

setData();
show("Original unsigned big-endian");


// swap the value using 16-bit array
for(var i = 0, v; i < b16.length; i++) {
  v = b16[i];
  b16[i] = ((v & 0xff) << 8) | ((v & 0xff00) >>> 8);
}
show("Byte-order swapped 16-bits");

setData();
for(var i = 0, v; i < b32.length; i++) {
  v = b32[i];
  b32[i] = ((v & 0xff) << 24) |
           ((v & 0xff00) << 8) |
           ((v & 0xff0000) >>> 8) |
           ((v & 0xff000000) >>> 24);
}
show("Byte-order swapped 32-bits");

setData();
for(var i = 0, v; i < buffer.byteLength; i += 2) {
  v = view.getUint16(i, false);  // big-endian
  view.setUint16(i, v, true);    // little-endian
}
show("Byte-order swapped 16-bit using DataView");

setData();
for(var i = 0, v; i < buffer.byteLength; i += 4) {
  v = view.getUint32(i, false);  // big-endian
  view.setUint32(i, v, true);    // little-endian
}
show("Byte-order swapped 32-bit using DataView");


function valToHex(v) {
  return (v>>>0).toString(16)
}

function setData() {
  b8[0] = 255;   // "network" order / big.endian 0xff804020
  b8[1] = 128;
  b8[2] = 64;
  b8[3] = 32;
}

function show(pre) {
  document.write(pre + ": ");
  document.write("0x" + valToHex(b8[0]));
  document.write(valToHex(b8[1]));
  document.write(valToHex(b8[2]));
  document.write(valToHex(b8[3]) + "<br>");
}
```

```css
body {font:16px monospace}
```

Comment: lol I really wasn't thinking. Of course Uint8s are just single bytes. Thanks for your detailed and thorough answer.